# how to mark and plot boundries using the threshold on an image using skimage

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection, image-segmentation, scikit-image

I have an image of these coins

[image: these coins]

I have tried the algorithms using the `skimage.filters` on the grayscale version of this. I want to know that how do I find the lines around these coins and plot `contours` over coins in the original image.

I have used

```
img = io.imread('coins.jpg')
img = color.rgb2gray(img)
f,ax = filters.try_all_threshold(img,verbose=False,figsize=(8,15))
_ = ax[0].set_title('Grayscale version of Original')
```

Comment: first do rgb2gray transformation, then you can do Otsu Thresholding, after that do Sobel filtering to obtain edges, at this point, you will have the contour, for labelling there is a built-in function in Scikit-Image.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few different ways to find out the outer boundaries of the coins. But which method to pick depends on what you want to achieve with that result.

@Belal Homaidan has already pointed one such solution. You can also use canny edge detector and then apply Hough transform. Here's an example:

[Circular and Elliptical Hough Transforms](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/edges/plot_circular_elliptical_hough_transform.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-edges-plot-circular-elliptical-hough-transform-py)

EDIT:

The most relevant part for you as per your question, perhaps, is following:

```
# Draw them
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=1, nrows=1, figsize=(10, 4))
image = color.gray2rgb(image)
for center_y, center_x, radius in zip(cy, cx, radii):
    circy, circx = circle_perimeter(center_y, center_x, radius,
                                    shape=image.shape)
    image[circy, circx] = (220, 20, 20)

ax.imshow(image, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
plt.show()
```